# PrintDocument: Parse index

Tags: c#, for-loop

See my code below. The code will fail here: `person[i].Pic`, because `i` is unknown.

How can I pass index `i` to `PrintPage()`-method?

```
private void BtnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    for (int i = 0; i < persons.Count(); i++)
    {
        PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
        pd.PrintPage += PrintPage;
        pd.Print();
    }
}

private void PrintPage(object o, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{            
    System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(person[i].Pic);
    Point loc = new Point(400, 100);
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, loc);

}
```

Comment: Use an anonymous method?

Comment: You're adding them as events and accessing global `person`... not sure what you're trying to do but it sounds like bad design

Comment: oh btw i recommend to change `persons` to `Persons` so you know its not a local variable (pascal case)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
private void BtnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    for (int i = 0; i < persons.Count(); i++)
    {
        PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();

        pd.PrintPage += 
            delegate(object o, PrintPageEventArgs e)
            {            
                var img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(person[i].Pic);
                Point loc = new Point(400, 100);
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, loc);
            };

        pd.Print();
    }
}
```

I.e. use an [anonymous method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/anonymous-methods) that has access to the outer `i` variable.